# How to move minimized components placed at the bottom of the container?

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe, mouse-listeners

I have three components in a container and buttons in it. When I hit the minimize button the components gets minimized to the bottom of the container and when I hit the minimized component then it gets maximized.

Suppose three components are lying at the bottom and if I maximize the 2nd component then it gets maximized and the 3rd minimized component does not take the position of the 2nd and this remains as space.

Screenshot
[image]

```
package Project;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameTitlePane;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameUI;

public class Test2 {

    public Test2() throws HeadlessException, PropertyVetoException {
        createAndShowGUI();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new Test2();
                } catch (HeadlessException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } catch (PropertyVetoException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    private void createAndShowGUI() throws HeadlessException, PropertyVetoException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        final JDesktopPane jdp = new JDesktopPane() {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(600, 400);
            }
        };

        frame.setContentPane(jdp);
        frame.pack();

        createAndAddInternalFrame(jdp, 0, 0);
        createAndAddInternalFrame(jdp, 300, 0);
        createAndAddInternalFrame(jdp, 1, 200);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createAndAddInternalFrame(final JDesktopPane jdp, int x, int y) throws PropertyVetoException {
        final JInternalFrame jInternalFrame = new JInternalFrame("", true, true, true, true);
        jInternalFrame.setLocation(x, y);

        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        JLabel jl=new JLabel("panel"+x);

        JButton jb = new JButton("_");
        JButton jb2 = new JButton("[]");
        JButton jb3 = new JButton("X");

        jInternalFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
jp.add(jl);
        jp.add(jb);
        jp.add(jb2);
        jp.add(jb3);

        jInternalFrame.add(jp);

        jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                try {
                    if (jInternalFrame.getLayer() == JDesktopPane.FRAME_CONTENT_LAYER) {
                        jdp.remove(jInternalFrame);
                        jdp.add(jInternalFrame, JDesktopPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
                        jdp.revalidate();
                        jdp.repaint();
                    }
                    jInternalFrame.pack();
                    jInternalFrame.setIcon(true);
                } catch (PropertyVetoException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        jb2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                try {
                    if (jInternalFrame.isMaximum()) {//restore
                        jInternalFrame.pack();
                    } else {//maximize
                        jInternalFrame.setMaximum(true);
                    }
                    jdp.remove(jInternalFrame);
                    jdp.add(jInternalFrame, JDesktopPane.FRAME_CONTENT_LAYER);
                    jdp.revalidate();
                    jdp.repaint();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        jb3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                try {
                    jInternalFrame.dispose();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

        BasicInternalFrameTitlePane titlePane = (BasicInternalFrameTitlePane) ((BasicInternalFrameUI) jInternalFrame.getUI()).getNorthPane();
        jInternalFrame.remove(titlePane);

        jInternalFrame.pack();
        jInternalFrame.setVisible(true);
        jdp.repaint();

        jdp.add(jInternalFrame);
    }
}
```

Comment: See [How to write mouse listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer is it linked with mouse listener? I dont think so

Comment: Sorry, read it as "user moves"

Comment: @MadProgrammer sorry but i did not find any thing related to my question. Can you sort it out?

Comment: @MadProgrammer shouldn't he consider using `GridBagLayout` and then decrease the x coordinate of the components based on some calculations ? That is what I get of it :)

Comment: @LittleChild He's essentially using a null layout manager.  This makes him responsible for updating the layouts

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yeah, if he uses `GridBagLayout` then he is basically done. You are the extreme programmer. Why don't you rewrite his code and implement that functionality ?

Comment: From what I can gleen (and memory), the `DesktopManager` is responsible for the management of the internal frames, including "iconifying" them, but I don't see any listeners.  The other problem is, also, the iconified representation of the internal frames is handled by a different class (so you couldn't just check for all the frames that are minimized and shuffle them).  I would imagain if your desperate, you could supply you own `DesktopManager`, but that's a lot of work for little gain.

Comment: @LittleChild I don't think `GridBagLayout` will do what he wants (based on his previous question) and I'm working on a trig problem - I hate trig :(

Comment: @MadProgrammer trig ? Trigonometry ? You can try [Khan Academy](http://www.khanacademy.org) if you need resources :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested this with Metal and Windows L&F, you might need to test it with some others.

Basically, when the component is invalidated and the `doLayout` method is called, we check for the existence of any `JInternalFrame.JDesktopIcon` components.  We then take these and layout them out as we like...

```
public class TestInternalFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestInternalFrame();
    }

    private int xpos = 0;
    private int ypos = 0;

    public TestInternalFrame() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                }
                DesktopPane pane = new DesktopPane();
                pane.add(newInternalFrame());
                pane.add(newInternalFrame());
                pane.add(newInternalFrame());

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(pane);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setSize(400, 400);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }

    public JInternalFrame newInternalFrame() {
        JInternalFrame inf = new JInternalFrame("Blah", true, true, true, true);
        inf.setLocation(xpos, ypos);
        inf.setSize(100, 100);
        inf.setVisible(true);

        xpos += 50;
        ypos += 50;

        return inf;
    }

    public class DesktopPane extends JDesktopPane {

        @Override
        public void doLayout() {
            super.doLayout();
            List<Component> icons = new ArrayList<Component>(25);
            for (Component comp : getComponents()) {
                if (comp instanceof JInternalFrame.JDesktopIcon) {
                    icons.add(comp);
                }
            }

            int x = 0;
            for (Component icon : icons) {

                int y = getHeight() - icon.getHeight();
                icon.setLocation(x, y);
                x += icon.getWidth();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Make no mistake, this is a rough hack

**Updated**

```
int x = 0;
for (Component icon : icons) {
    int y = getHeight() - icon.getHeight();
    icon.setLocation(x, y);
    x += icon.getWidth();
    setLayer(icon, 10); // <--- Add me
}
```

To your other problem, you simply need to move the icon to a higher layer.  The problem with this, is you actually need to find a layer high enough.  You could use `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, but that's a little harsh (and you might want something over the top of the that), instead, you could calculate the maximum layer and sit +1 ontop of that...

```
public void doLayout() {
    super.doLayout();
    List<Component> icons = new ArrayList<Component>(25);
    int maxLayer = 0;
    for (Component comp : getComponents()) {
        if (comp instanceof JInternalFrame.JDesktopIcon) {
            icons.add(comp);
            maxLayer = Math.max(getLayer(comp), maxLayer);
        }
    }

    maxLayer++;
    int x = 0;
    for (Component icon : icons) {

        int y = getHeight() - icon.getHeight();
        icon.setLocation(x, y);
        x += icon.getWidth();
        setLayer(icon, maxLayer);

    }
}
```

You really need to take the the time to study [How to use Internal Frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html) and [How to use Layered Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) as (at least the last part) is covered in these...

Comment: thanks for posting your answer but it fulfills half answer. As i said you before the minimized frame should be visible when i max one frame. But in case the max frame overlaps all the other frames(even it is in orginal postion or in minimized state) I hope you have understood my requirement

Comment: thanks for your post .you might have seen my original code which shows that i have created my own buttons for max,min etc. But in this code we are using the default buttons. So i am wandering to know if we create our own buttons then will it function here and after max will the min panels move away

Comment: If I understand correctly (IIUC), you can use `Action` to encapsulate functionality, as suggested in the example cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8542622/230513).

Comment: @sukant So long as you are using the internal frame's min/max/restore functionality you should be fine

Comment: @MadProgrammer see the 2nd picture I want not to use inbuilt buttons like min/max/restore.I want to create my own buttons so i am asking for that

Comment: @sukant You really need to start reading the [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html).  You can either use the `DesktopManager` directly, or use [`JInternalFrame#setIcon`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html#setIcon%28boolean%29) and [`JInternalFrame#setMaximum`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html#setMaximum%28boolean%29) to change the state of the `JInternalFrame`, which is what I said in the previous comment ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer i have done already buttons on my own ,just i need to implement it. Yes you are right i should read but actually i have much  work and has absolutely no time for read,so asking for your help

Answer (score 1):

Something like that:

```
jdp.setDesktopManager( new DefaultDesktopManager(){
    @Override
    public void deiconifyFrame(JInternalFrame f) {
        super.deiconifyFrame(f);
        JDesktopPane d = f.getDesktopPane();
         JInternalFrame[] frames = d.getAllFrames();
         for(JInternalFrame frame : frames ) {
             Rectangle bounds = getBoundsForIconOf(frame);
              // relayout all frames
         }
    }
});
```

Comment: I like your idea, but you're potentially changing the default behavior of the `JDesktop` under different platforms (I know, because the Windows implementation had a bug in it for awhile and we had to switch it out for a different one :P))

Comment: interesting reply, i didn't know

Comment: @oliholz sorry but its not working. Can you try in any other way?

Comment: We spent 4 weeks trying to track this problem (switch from Metal to Windows and it all feel apart) - ended up relying on the `DefaultDesktopManager` I think

Comment: @oliholz It's more of a "beware" then anything, still a nice idea.

Comment: @sukant You need to be a little more descriptive over what's not working.  What did you try, where do you think it failed...

Comment: @MadProgrammer See there are three internal frames.I am minimizing all then it comes down(i mean to the bottom of the  container). Again i am maximizing the internal frame(present at the bottom) then it gets maximized but it also overlaps all the internal frames(even the minized frame are also  not visible)

Comment: @MadProgrammer did you get my requirement?