# internal frame not working

Tags: java, swing

Hi I have created three frames inside a container and each frame has three buttons which performs the functions of min,max and close. For surprise only one frame is working and the rest three are not working.can you please sort it out.thanks

```
      package Project;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameTitlePane;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameUI;

public class Test4 {
      JInternalFrame inf ;
      DesktopPane pane;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test4();
    }

    private int xpos = 0;
    private int ypos = 0;

    public Test4() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                }
                pane = new DesktopPane();
                pane.add(newInternalFrame());
                pane.add(newInternalFrame());
                pane.add(newInternalFrame());

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(pane);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setSize(400, 400);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }

    public JInternalFrame newInternalFrame() {
      inf= new JInternalFrame("Blah", true, true, true, true);
        inf.setLocation(xpos, ypos);
        inf.setSize(200, 100);
        inf.setVisible(true);

        xpos += 50;
        ypos += 50;

        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        JLabel jl=new JLabel("panel"+xpos);

        JButton jb = new JButton("_");
        JButton jb2 = new JButton("[]");
        JButton jb3 = new JButton("X");

        inf.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
jp.add(jl);
        jp.add(jb);
        jp.add(jb2);
        jp.add(jb3);

        inf.add(jp);
        jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                try {
                    if (inf.getLayer() == JDesktopPane.FRAME_CONTENT_LAYER) {
                        pane.remove(inf);
                        pane.add(inf, JDesktopPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
                        pane.revalidate();
                        pane.repaint();
                    }
                    inf.pack();
                    inf.setIcon(true);
                } catch (PropertyVetoException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        jb2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                try {
                    if (inf.isMaximum()) {//restore
                        inf.pack();
                    } else {//maximize
                        inf.setMaximum(true);

                    }
                    pane.remove(inf);
                    pane.add(inf, JDesktopPane.FRAME_CONTENT_LAYER);
                    pane.revalidate();
                    pane.repaint();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        jb3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                try {
                    inf.dispose();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });


        BasicInternalFrameTitlePane titlePane = (BasicInternalFrameTitlePane) ((BasicInternalFrameUI) inf.getUI()).getNorthPane();
        inf.remove(titlePane);
        return inf;
    }

    public class DesktopPane extends JDesktopPane {

        @Override
        public void doLayout() {
            super.doLayout();
            List<Component> icons = new ArrayList<Component>(25);
            int maxLayer = 0;

            for (Component comp : getComponents()) {
                if (comp instanceof JInternalFrame.JDesktopIcon) {
                    icons.add(comp);
                    maxLayer = Math.max(getLayer(comp), maxLayer);
                }
            }

            maxLayer++;
            int x = 0;
            for (Component icon : icons) {

                int y = getHeight() - icon.getHeight();
                icon.setLocation(x, y);
                x += icon.getWidth();
                setLayer(icon, maxLayer);

            }
        }
     /*   public void doLayout() {
            super.doLayout();
            List<Component> icons = new ArrayList<Component>(25);
            for (Component comp : getComponents()) {
                if (comp instanceof JInternalFrame.JDesktopIcon) {
                    icons.add(comp);
                }
            }

            int x = 0;
            for (Component icon : icons) {

                int y = getHeight() - icon.getHeight();
                icon.setLocation(x, y);
                x += icon.getWidth();

            }
        }*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a debugger? You need to put some honest effort into solving your own problem before dumping it to a public site like SO.

Comment: *For surprise only one frame is working and the rest three are not working.can you please sort it out* it had to work at some point (i.e [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14873889/how-to-keep-minimized-jinternalframe-on-top/14874165)) so surely you can narrow down the changes which are causing this?

Comment: @Perception thanks for good advice .I didnt know it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
package Project;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameTitlePane;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameUI;

public class Test4 {

    private JDesktopPane pane;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test4();// there was a little change here
    }
    private int xpos = 0;
    private int ypos = 0;

    public Test4() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                }
                pane = new Test4.DesktopPane() {
                    @Override
                    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                        return new Dimension(400, 400);
                    }
                };
                pane.add(newInternalFrame());
                pane.add(newInternalFrame());
                pane.add(newInternalFrame());

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(pane);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }

    public JInternalFrame newInternalFrame() {
        final JInternalFrame inf = new JInternalFrame("Blah", true, true, true, true);
        inf.setLocation(xpos, ypos);
        inf.setSize(200, 100);
        inf.setVisible(true);

        xpos += 50;
        ypos += 50;

        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        JLabel jl = new JLabel("panel" + xpos);

        JButton jb = new JButton("_");
        JButton jb2 = new JButton("[]");
        JButton jb3 = new JButton("X");

        inf.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        jp.add(jl);
        jp.add(jb);
        jp.add(jb2);
        jp.add(jb3);

        inf.add(jp);
        jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                try {
                    if (inf.getLayer() == JDesktopPane.FRAME_CONTENT_LAYER) {
                        pane.remove(inf);
                        pane.add(inf, JDesktopPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
                        pane.revalidate();
                        pane.repaint();
                    }
                    inf.pack();
                    inf.setIcon(true);
                } catch (PropertyVetoException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        jb2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                try {
                    if (inf.isMaximum()) {//restore
                        inf.pack();
                    } else {//maximize
                        inf.setMaximum(true);

                    }
                    pane.remove(inf);
                    pane.add(inf, JDesktopPane.FRAME_CONTENT_LAYER);
                    pane.revalidate();
                    pane.repaint();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        jb3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                try {
                    inf.dispose();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });


        BasicInternalFrameTitlePane titlePane = (BasicInternalFrameTitlePane) ((BasicInternalFrameUI) inf.getUI()).getNorthPane();
        inf.remove(titlePane);
        return inf;
    }

    public class DesktopPane extends JDesktopPane {

        @Override
        public void doLayout() {
            super.doLayout();
            List<Component> icons = new ArrayList<Component>(25);
            int maxLayer = 0;

            for (Component comp : getComponents()) {
                if (comp instanceof JInternalFrame.JDesktopIcon) {
                    icons.add(comp);
                    maxLayer = Math.max(getLayer(comp), maxLayer);
                }
            }

            maxLayer++;
            int x = 0;
            for (Component icon : icons) {

                int y = getHeight() - icon.getHeight();
                icon.setLocation(x, y);
                x += icon.getWidth();
                setLayer(icon, maxLayer);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just add the following line

```
final JInternalFrame inf= new JInternalFrame("Blah", true, true, true, true);
```

in place of `inf= new JInternalFrame("Blah", true, true, true, true);`

and remove this `JInternalFrame inf` from main.

Comment: @DavidKroukamp actual credit goes to HarryJoy. he is the first. and i want to upvote him but he removed his ans. i also upvoted you because your ans is correct too. :)

Comment: but if i do in this way whole my project runs in a wrong way. my job was to do like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14889369/how-to-move-minimized-components-placed-at-the-bottom-of-the-container so i tried this way but unfortunately this is not working